Is it possible to change the location of a reference in Excel VBA References?
I have developed a VBA script which allows the user to input the dimensions of an object in Excel which is then drawn in plan and section in Microstation Connect. A colleague has attempted to use the tool and received an error from Microsoft Visual Basic which says:
*Run-time error '-2147417851 (80010105)':
Method 'CreateLineElement2' of object'_Application' failed. *
One thing which appears different between our systems is the Location of the Bentley MicroStation 10.x Object Library 10.1. The location on my computer points to the MicroStation Connect program files, whereas on my colleagues it points to an OpenSite Designer folder.
We have browsed to the EXE file in my colleagues Microstation program files but the location does not update. Is it possible to change this location, to rule out whether this is causing the issue?
Location pointing to MicroStation Connect folder
Location incorrectly pointing to OpenSite Connect folder

You might try adding the reference programmatically using VBA.
